# HEX output to String c++

Tags: c++, string, hex, stringstream

I am trying to convert a `printf` output to a `std::string` variable. I have the following for loop:

```cpp
for(i=0; i<53; i++) {
    printf("%02X", pbRecvBuffer[i]);
}
```

The output of this loop are hex values like: `01445420434F2..`. My first attempt was using `stringstream` as the following:

```cpp
stringstream os;

for(i=0; i<53; i++) 
    os << std::hex << pbRecvBuffer[i];

std::cout << os << std::endl;
```

unfortunately this is given me the wrong result. Maybe someone just see it directly and can help me out.

Comment: What are some of the values in `pbRecvBuffer`? What is the result? Simply saying that you get the wrong result won't get you any useful answers.

Comment: std::hex converts ints, lets strings pass through unchanged; you probably have an array of char here? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex ("Modifies the default numeric base for *integer* I/O)

Comment: `std::hex` is what you want. Just write it to the stream using `std::cout << std::hex << your_hext_here;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general with streams that are in hex and int for example is a good idea to:

```
std::ios_base::fmtflags f(out.flags()); // Init

out <<std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)pbRecvBuffer[i];

out.flags(f); // restore
```

In general out is an object derived from std::cout, std::ostringstream, std::basic_ostream and so on

Comment: Many thanks. Can you tell me what out is in that case?